# Prove $\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^2+16x+1}}}\geqslant 1$ and $ \sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{4x^2+10x+4}}}\leqslant 1$ for $x,y,z>0,xyz=1$

Tags: inequality

Source: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2745656_inequalities_with_3

Let $x,y,z>0,xyz=1$ then $$
\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^2+16x+1}}}\geqslant 1  \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
and$$
\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{4x^2+10x+4}}}\leqslant 1\ \ \ (2)
$$
For this type of inequalities, I usually use local inequalities$$
x,y,z>0,xyz=1,\sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}}\geqslant 1, \sum_{cyc}{\frac{x^2}{x^2+x+1}}\geqslant 1, \sum_{cyc}{\frac{x+1}{x^2+x+1}}\leqslant 2
$$
For (1) it's smooth,because$$
\frac{x^4+1}{x^8+16 x^4+1}-\left(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\right)^2=\frac{(x-1)^2 x \left(2 x^4+7 x^3+14 x^2+7 x+2\right)}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2 \left(x^8+16 x^4+1\right)} \geqslant 0$$
Then it's easy to prove.
But for (2) I get
$$\frac{x^2+1}{4 x^4+10 x^2+4}-\left(\frac{x+1}{2 \left(x^2+x+1\right)}\right)^2=\frac{(x-1)^2 x^2}{4 \left(x^2+2\right) \left(x^2+x+1\right)^2 \left(2 x^2+1\right)} \geqslant 0$$
Then $$
\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{4x^2+10x+4}}}\geqslant \sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{x+\sqrt{x}+1}}\leqslant 1
$$
Failed. How can I prove (2)? Any solution is welcome.

Comment: Some proofs are given in OP's link: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2745656_inequalities_with_3

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

For $x\leq 0$ we have :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}f\left(e^{x}\right)\right)<0$$

Where :

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{4x^{2}+4+10x}}$$

Next we show that for $x>0$ and $n= 3$ a natural number :

$$f\left(x\right)+\left(n-1\right)f\left(\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n-1}}}\right)-nf\left(1\right)\leq 0$$

In the case $n=3$ we can use the bound given in the link https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2745656_inequalities_with_3

We have for $x>0$:

$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+3x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{4x^{2}+4+10x}}\geq 0$$

To show this inequality we use the substitution $y^2=3x+1$ then square both side then clearing the denominator and use a [factorization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor%20%28%28%28x%C2%B2-1%29%2F3%2B1%29%2F%284%28%28x%C2%B2-1%29%2F3%29%C2%B2%2B4%2B10%28%28x%C2%B2-1%29%2F3%29%29%29-1%2F%281%2Bx%29%C2%B2) .

So we need to show :

$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+3x}}+2\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+3x^{-0.5}}}-3\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+3}}\leq 0$$

Wich is easy !

So now we can apply the LCF corollary (first reference) and conclude .

Last remark : We have also the  case $n=4$ for $a_i\in(e^{-1},e^{1})$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^{4}a_i=1$.

Reference :

1. Cirtoaje and Baiesu: An extension of Jensen’s discrete inequality to half convex functions.
   Journal of Inequalities and Applications 2011 2011:101.

2)https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2745656_inequalities_with_3

---

---

---

Edit 11/02/2022 :

For $0<x\leq 1$ we have :

$$\frac{\left(x+2\right)\left(x+1\right)}{\frac{11}{2}x^{2}+4+\frac{17}{2}x}\geq f(x)$$

On the other hand we have $x\geq 1$ :

$$h\left(x\right)=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{1.5x^{-0.5}+1.5}\geq f(x)$$

Edit 12/02/2022 :

We can do better on $x\in (0,1]$ we have :

$$r(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{7}{2}x+2}{4x^{2}+4+10x}\geq f(x)$$

Using the same approach as above we have on $(-\infty,0]$ :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}r\left(e^{x}\right)\right)<0$$

So we have for $0<a\leq 1$ and $0<b\leq 1$ and $c\geq 1$ :

$$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\leq 2r(\sqrt{ab})+h(c)=2r(\sqrt{ab})+h(1/ab)\leq 1$$

Wich is smooth .

*For the other case I use Buffalo's ways see* [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Dc%5E%7B4%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B7%7D%7B2%7Dc%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%7D%7B4c%5E%7B4%7D%2B4%2B10c%5E%7B2%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1.5%281%2F%28b%2B1%29c%29%5E%7B-1%7D%2B1.5%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1.5%28b%2B1%29%5E%7B-1%7D%2B1.5%7D-1%20)

*I made a mistake I solve another problem ...

Here you can find the solution for the other case wich use Buffalo's way

See [Wolfram alpha (2)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%28%28a%2B1%29%28b%2B1%29%29%5E%7B-4%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B7%7D%7B2%7D%28%28a%2B1%29%28b%2B1%29%29%5E%7B-2%7D%2B2%7D%7B4%28%28a%2B1%29%28b%2B1%29%29%5E%7B-4%7D%2B4%2B10%28%28a%2B1%29%28b%2B1%29%29%5E%7B-2%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1.5%281%2Ba%29%5E%7B-1%7D%2B1.5%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1.5%281%2Bb%29%5E%7B-1%7D%2B1.5%7D-1%20).

Comment: Would you please give some details, e.g. which theorem did you use?  The paper is "Reciprocally convex functions" by MilanMerkle, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Volume 293, Issue 1, 1 May 2004, Pages 210-218.

Comment: I think the paper does not give the result: $f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)+f\left(c\right)\leq 3f\left(\left(abc\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$. In Theorem 2.3, eq. (4), it only gives $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \le 3f(\frac{3}{1/a + 1/b + 1/c})$ which is weaker than $f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)+f\left(c\right)\leq 3f\left(\left(abc\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @RiverLi it's just the substitution $x=e^u$ see the page 215 of the same paper .

Comment: I don't understand you. Would you please write down the detailed proof?

Comment: In Theorem 3.1, you need the assumption $f(e^x)$ is concave on $(-\infty, \infty)$, or convex on $(-\infty, \infty)$. If you let $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\left(x+1\right)}{4x^2+10x+4}}$, then $f(e^x)$ is neither concave nor convex on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks for help me now it's fixed with a partial proof !

Comment: @RiverLi Can you show the inequality related to my edit ?

Comment: Is your edit a full proof for the original problem? If so, we are interested in it and you can write down the details. If no, we wait for a full proof.

Comment: @RiverLi see my edits !

Comment: @RiverLi it's a variant does it matter ?

Comment: In your edit, if you have a different proof from the proofs in the link (but use the bound given in the link), you may write down details. For example, why "So we need to show"?

Comment: @I have not the time yet but no problem !:-)

Comment: @RiverLi To show the inequality in question I use the linear transformation $y=3x+1$ next square both side the rest is smooth.I guess you show the inequality like this so I'm thinking to another proof . For your second question see the first reference and LCF corollary .

Comment: You should write down the details (step-by-step). You mixed different content such as partial hint,  edit, edit again. It is not nice. You may delete the partial hint and focus on your main proof. Or keep partial hint and post a new answer.

Comment: @RiverLi see my edits thanks for the advices .

Comment: It is hard for me to read your proof. First, you can focus on $n = 3$ and give remark (at the end or at the beginning) for general $n$. Second, how is the 1st paragrph "for $x \le 0$ we have $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}f\left(e^{x}\right)\right)<0$" related to your proof?

Comment: By the way, I did not downvote your another answer.

Comment: @RiverLi see the condition related to the LCF corollary (first reference).

Comment: @RiverLi what do you think about my two last bound ? Thanks for your advices !

Comment: If you provide a full proof, we are interested in it.

Comment: @RiverLi See my edits . Hope you can find something pleasant .:-)

Comment: It is not a full proof, right? Can you write down step-by-step proof for the OP? I don't understand your Edit 12/02/2022 at all.

Comment: @RiverLi The bounds are really simple to show and again it's a simple use of Jensen's inequality where I use the second derivative but I can add the details even if I have not the time today .See you tomorrow .

Comment: You should write down step-by-step solution (all details). You can do it in the future when you are not busy.